# git ignore all .DS_Store files

Tags: git

I have untracked files:

```
src/main/.DS_Store
src/main/java/.DS_Store
src/main/java/com/.DS_Store
```

I would like to git ignore all of those .DS_Store files. I tried putting `**/.DS_Store` in `.gitignore` , but no effect. Why? How to ignore them?

Comment: Are you sure these are currently *untracked?* If they are currently tracked, listing them in `.gitignore` will have no effect. Does `git status` put them in the "untracked files" section, or is it saying that you have changes `not staged for commit` or `staged for commit`?

Answer (score 2):

If .DS_Store was never added to your git repository, simply add it to your .gitignore file.

**If you don't have one, create a file called**

```
.gitignore
```

In your the root directory of your app and simply write

```
.DS_Store
._.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
**/._.DS_Store
```

In it. This will never allow the .DS_Store file to sneak in your git.

**if it's already there, write in your terminal:**

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch
```

then commit and push the changes to remove the .DS_Store from your remote repo:

```
git commit -m "Remove .DS_Store from everywhere"
git push origin master
```

And now add .DS_Store to your .gitignore file, and then again commit and push with the 2 last pieces of code (git commit..., git push...)

**Other Solution**

If .DS_Store already committed:

```
find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm --ignore-unmatch
```

To ignore them in all repository: (sometimes it named ._.DS_Store)

```
echo ".DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
echo "**/._.DS_Store" >> ~/.gitignore_global
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

**Dang!**

Answer (score 1):

A plain `.DS_Store` on a single row should do it.

I have that row, and others, in my [`~/.gitignore_global`](https://github.com/chelmertz/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitignore_global) which makes it unnecessary to add that line to every git repository everywhere.

You can setup a global gitignore file with this configuration in your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[core]
        excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

and then keep on filling it up with more artifacts present on your system (IMO putting `.DS_Store` in the .gitignore of a project that is used by more developers than only those using Mac is a bit spammy, you can end up with *a lot* of different file patterns there.)

---

edit after comment:

This is what happens for me:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .DS_Store
    asdf2/.DS_Store

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ echo .DS_Store > .gitignore
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .gitignore

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: I added `.DS_Store` on a single row in my `.gitignore` but it doesn't help , I still see those .DS_Store files with `git status`

Comment: I edited my answer with what happens on my system (after I removed my system's "global gitignore", sorry for that spammy part of this answer)

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by "!" directives in the `.gitignore` file.

If your project is a gradle project, gradle  default `.gitignore` contains the lines

```
!**/src/main/**
!**/src/test/**
```

which **keeps** (because of the `!`) *everything* in `src/main`. If you have a complex project, with multiple `.gitignore`, the innermost `.gitignore` takes precedence. Thus, my main project had a `.DS_Store` line in its root `.gitignore`, but it was overridden by the (inner) gradle projects standard `.gitignore`.

Hence the solution :
put the line `.DS_Store` somewhere *after* the

```
!**/src/main/**
!**/src/test/**
```

lines of your project (or alternatively, in a `.gitignore` in `src`, but this might be less practical.

With :

```
!**/src/main/**
!**/src/test/**
.DS_Store
```

everything should be fine.